# Branch specific path filter in ci trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there an possibility to define path filter per branch for ci triggers?
i want to always run ci on main branch and only if a specific file has changed on develop branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths filter is applied to all the branches which can match the branches filter. In a pipeline, we have no method to set paths filter for each branch individually.

As the workaround, you can try like as below:

1. Set up a pipeline for each branch with different paths filter.
2. When you make changes on the develop branch, if the changed files do not contain the specific file, you can add the keywords **`[skip ci]`** or **`[ci skip]`** in the commit message to skip the CI trigger. For more details, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-pushes).